# How does Origin Protocol Policy overlap with Viewer Protocol Policy?

Tags: https, http, amazon-cloudfront

The question is about [Amazon CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Introduction.html).

The names in the title refer to two types of settings. The former can be edited via the "Origins and Origin Groups" tab, while the latter via the "Behaviors" tab.

[image: Origin Protocol Policy]

[image: Viewer Protocol Policy]

What is the difference between the two? Do they influence one another in any way?